# How do I call function edit.draw from Leaflet in my button?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have created a button labeled `Edit` in my popup that appears once the user clicks the marker, but I am having problems calling the `edit.draw` function from [Leaflet Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) when the user clicks the button.

[image: Layout]

[image: Description]

Comment: Can you add what related code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually enable editing for the marker if you have a reference to the marker. Something like this:

```
var editClick = function(){
    if(marker && marker.editing)
        marker.editing.enable();
}
```